# nginx try_files without any files - internal redirect

Tags: nginx, server

Given:

```
    location ~ /foo/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /foohandler.py;
    }
```

`try_files`: "If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made" [1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

If I know `$uri` and `$uri/` will never exist, how do I always do an internal redirect to `/foohandler.py` without using `try_files`?

Using `try_files /foohandler.py` is invalid syntax. What is the proper equivalent? `return`? `rewrite`?

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ /foo/ {
  rewrite ^ /foohandler.py break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use try_files. It requires more than one parameter, so just add a 404 code to avoid the syntax error:

```
location ~ /foo/ {
    try_files /foohandler.py =404;
}
```

On a side note, if your uri always begins with /foo/ then a prefix location would be better:

```
location /foo/ {
    try_files /foohandler.py =404;
}
```

Comment: Would it work too with an internal redirect ? 
`location /foo/ {
    try_files @myInternalRedirect =404;
}`

Comment: I don't see why not. Give it a try.